# To restrict the JSON data to fixed length

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an **JSON** file called `customers`,as show in the below:

`customers.json`

```
[
  {
    "name": "Customer 1",
    "id": "01"
  },
  {
    "name": "Customer 2",
    "id": "02"
  },
  {
    "name": "Customer 3",
    "id": "03"
  }
  ,
  {
    "name": "Customer 4",
    "id": "04"
  }
]
```

For this **JSON** i need to perform two operations:

- On loading the `component`, I need to show **only 1st two objects of the** JSON  (i,e customer 1 & 2) like this:

[image]

- On clicking the `Show more` button it should show the remaining objects(i,e all 4 customers) like this:

[image]

**[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-azzgx5?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in appComponent declare a variable

```
showmore:boolean=false;
```

in Html

```
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let customer of customers; let i =index">
  <p *ngIf="!showmore&&(i<=1)">{{customer.name}} </p>
<p *ngIf="showmore">{{customer.name}} </p>
</div>
<button (click)="showmore=!showmore">Show More</button>
```

Comment: Your solution work fine,but After clicking `show more` button then the button text should change to `show less`

Comment: change the content of button like this : {{(showmore==true)?"Show less":"Show more"}}

Comment: I am unable to write `!showmore&&(i<=1)` condition in the template , It is showing error in my app but works fine `stackblitz`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Please give solution i,e `show more` and `show less` for `session objects` in this link: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-yqm6v3?file=src/app/app.component.html**

Comment: <div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let teacher of teachers;let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="(showmore==false &&i<=0)||showmore==true">  

 <tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>{{teacher.teacherName }}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Sessions</td>
  <td><br>
      <div *ngFor="let item of getSessionForTeacher(teacher.id)">
      <p>{{item.sessionName}}</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr> 
       
 <hr>
  </div>
</div>
 <button (click)="showmore=!showmore">{{(showmore)?"Show less":"Show more"}}</button>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192250/discussion-between-shankar-and-arunkumar-m-n).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
export class AppComponent  {
  customers: ICustomer[];
  topCust = [];

  constructor(private myService: ContactService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getCustomers()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.customers = res;
        this.topCust.push(this.customers[0]);
        this.topCust.push(this.customers[1]);
        });
  }

  showMore() {
    this.topCust = this.customers;
  }



}
```

In HTML

```
<h4>Customers</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let customer of topCust">
<p>{{customer.name}}</p>
</div>
<button (click)="showMore()">Show More</button>
```

Comment: @shankar Please approve the solution if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain `showMode` and use it to control the `shownCustomers` e.g.

```
  shownCustomers: ICustomer[] = [];
  showMode: 'start'|'all' = 'start';

  constructor(private myService: ContactService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getCustomers()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.customers = res as any;
        this.updateShownCustomers();
      });
  }

  updateShownCustomers(){
    this.shownCustomers = this.showMode == 'all' ? this.customers : this.customers.slice(0,2);
  }

  toggle(){
    this.showMode = this.showMode == 'all' ? 'start' : 'all';
    this.updateShownCustomers();
  }
```

## Working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-hvunyk

## More

You can also use it power the `show more` / `show less` logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<h4>Customers</h4>

<ng-container *ngFor="let customer of customers;  let i=index">
  <p *ngIf="i<filterItems">{{customer.name}}</p>
</ng-container>
<button *ngIf="filterItems == 2" (click)="showMore()">Show More</button>
<button *ngIf="filterItems == 4" (click)="showLess()">Show Less</button>
```

In component: declare

```
  filterItems = 2;


  showMore(){
    this.filterItems = 4;
  }


  showLess(){
    this.filterItems = 2;
  }
```

Here is the working [**example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-hk7bmg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your component as:

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  customers: ICustomer[];
  showLimit = 2;
  stubArray = Array(this.showLimit).fill(1);

  constructor(private myService: ContactService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getCustomers()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.customers = res as ICustomer[];
        this.stubArray = Array(this.showLimit).fill(1);
      });
  }

  showTwoMore() {
    this.showLimit += 2;
    this.stubArray = Array(this.showLimit).fill(1);
  }
}
```

And then your template as:

```html
<h4>Customers</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let num of stubArray; let idx = index">
<p>{{customers[idx].name}}</p>
</div>
<button (click)="showTwoMore()">Show More</button>
```

Key things to look for in the above code are:

1. stubArray - Simple array with length in multiple of 2
2. showTwoMore - method to increment the stubArray length by 2

Done using a simple method. Please have a look at the working stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-azzgx5

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let customer of customers.slice(0,more?customers.length:2);  let i=index">
  <p >{{customer.name}}</p>
</ng-container>
<button (click)="more=true">Show More</button>
<button (click)="more=false">Show Less</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use css

```js
<div class="cust-container" [class.more]="more">
    <div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let customer of topCust">
        <p>{{customer.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button (click)="more = !more">{{ more ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}}</button>
```

```css
.cust-container > div {
  display: none;
}

.cust-container.more > div, .cust-container > div:nth-child(0), .cust-container > div:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}
```

Another solution without css

```js
<div class="cust-container" [class.more]="more">
    <div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let customer of topCust" [hidden]="!more && index > 1">
        <p>{{customer.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button (click)="more = !more">{{ more ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More'}}</button>
```